# Morphism category of a cocomplete category is also cocomplete?

Tags: category-theory

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with all small colimits (i.e., cocomplete), then can we tell that the morphism category $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ is also cocomplete?

Answer (score 2):

The arrow category is a functor category $[\mathbb I, \mathcal C]$, where $\mathbb I$ is the [interval category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/interval+category). Functor categories inherit colimits from their codomain, so the arrow category is cocomplete when $\mathcal C$ is.